# Service running in a different timezone than windows (with a specific user)

Tags: windows, timezone, settings, multiple-users

I have a service running in windows that is running with a particular user, different than the one that I sue to log on to the server. And the service user, is using a different time zone than the windows server.
I need to find out a way to see in which timezone is the user that is running the service configured. How can this be done from the windows server? to check the timezone of a specific user?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, because time zones in Windows are set at the computer level, not per user. The active time zone is saved in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation`.  The only exception I'm familiar with is if you're using [RDS time zone redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/termserv/win32-terminalservicesetting-settimezoneredirection).  It doesn't apply to a typical service.  Thus, to answer your question, please elaborate on precisely what you mean by "the service user is using a different time zone than the windows server".

Comment: Hope this clarifies, but we have a user, that is used to execute windows services of a specific applications, it is used along several servers in the same domain. If I see the logs of the service, the timezone registered is GMT, however the server timezone is UTC, so my assumption was that the user specifica has a timezone that is different than the server, and the question points to where to check that, in case it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but as I stated - time zones on Windows are not a per-user setting. Thus, I don't believe your assumption is valid.  Please edit your question to provide actual examples of the code and/or logs.  See also [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it was a bit strange to answer to this question as 'not possible' as i see the same behaviour on a server from one of our clients.

The timezone in Windows when logged on is correct, the date & time is shown correct in taskbar and yet the firebird database server service reports CURRENT_TIMESTAMP one hour earlier, UTC time, i suspect other services would also get a UTC time, i'm still checking that.
So it would seem the SYSTEM user uses a different timezone, i know people say that it's not possible but it sure looks that way...

If i check with firebird embedded, which is NOT a Service i get the correct time in UTC+1